# Neural network image architecture

Tags: opencv, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I've got a set of 16000 images. I've got one sample images, I need to find one of 16000 images on it. I've already tried OpenCV's ORB + FLANN approach, but it is too slow. I hope once trained network will be faster than it. I don't know NN theory well, I've read some articles & websites and I've got a bunch of questions:

1. Should I use 16k output neurons to classificate input image?
2. How can I train my NN if I have only one train image per class?
3. What architecture should I use?
4. Maybe I should increase training dataset by randomly distorting input images?

Sorry in advance for my bad English:)

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You have 16.000 images. You have a single image of each "class". You need the network to recognize each image. So you don't need to generalize the network classification, right?

Comment: @WillGlück Yes, you understood right. But I didn't understand your last sentence, sorry.

Comment: Usually neural networks are used for generalization. You show the network some images of cats and it will classify as cats other cat images never seen before. In your case, after the training, you will show images that the network never saw or just the images used for training?

Comment: @WillGlück I will show images that are similiar to training images, i.e. the photo of printed training image.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is an image retrieval problem? You have a db of 16K images, from an input image you want to find closest matching (not clear if semantically) image from your db, is it?

Comment: @kunal18 it was a year ago, but you are right:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think that this kind of problem is not the perfect suit for neural networks. Probably feature extraction, interest points and descriptors, all avaliable in openCV, are the best option. Anyway, let's try this. With the infos received, I think you could try this:

**SOM network** - Create a Self Organizing Maps network with 16.000 classes for output. Never saw a example with that many classes and just one sample per class, but it should work. Maybe you can try to use PCA to reduce the images dimensionality. Keep training the network with your images (or PCA features). Start with, I don't know, 1.000 epochs. Keep raising this value until you have good results.

[Here you can read a bit more about SOM](http://chem-eng.utoronto.ca/~datamining/Presentations/SOM.pdf)

Comment: What do we apply the PCA on? Directly on the Mat of the image or on the histogram of the image? Should the images be grayscale? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know you can do both. But, the most common use of PCA is on collected data of the raw image. Like histograms. 
About the grayscale, If there is important features that can be detected using the colors I guess grayscale is not a good choice.